# BAT File To Install and To Run Service

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I wrote a *bat* file to install Tomcat 7.0.73 and start its service:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
CD /D Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.73\bin\
service install MyTomcat
SLEEP 5
sc start MyTomcat
```

But there are 2 problems:

1. After *service install MyTomcat*, It exits and It does not perform the command *sc start MyTomcat*;
2. How can I change the script in order to start *MyTomcat* in a persistent way?

Comment: By default (at least on Windows 7) there is no command `service` and no command `sleep`. You would probably have to look into the documentation of those commands to figure out why it's not working the way you want and/or provide more context.

Comment: Thanks, but I am working with Windows 10

Comment: Which doesn't have a `service` command either, by default. So you will still need to provide context on where that command is coming from or check the help yourself, likely by running `service /?` or `service -h`.

Comment: If `service` is another batch file then `call` it.

Comment: Why have you deleted your account? Doing so means we can't @comment reply to you ...

Comment: @DavidPostill For reference to others, it is a batch-file  `service.bat` See [Apache Tomcat - Windows service HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Command_line_arguments)